# Can someone help me with this Python. Replacing string in txt file

Tags: python, string, replace, io

I'm quite new to python and I'm trying to create a Login system where you are able to change your username. I have been through multiple forums but cannot find anything that works. Can you please tell me what is going wrong with  the code. The error that it comes up with is this: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'. If that helps. The following is the code:

```
print("What would you like your username to be changed to?")
C2 = input()
file = open("Info.txt", 'r+')
file.write(file.replace(A1, C2))
```

Comment: `file` is a file, not a string. Given that you named it `file`, it's not clear why this appears unexpected!

Comment: Several issues, "A1" is not defined, and you're trying to do a string replace on a file object. Not sure how you're storing the data in your file, but you could read your file by lines/tokens, and replace the username at the desired line to the new username.

Answer (score 2):

`file` is a `file` object, not a string! If you want the contents of the file, do:

```
s = file.read()
```

which will give you its content as a string (which has a method `replace`).

To write it back to the same file, you would have to open it again in writing mode:

```
file = open("Info.txt", 'w')
file.write(s.replace(A1, C2))
file.close()
```

Comment: Once you successfully call `replace()`, you'll still need to rewrite the file to contain the new contents.

Comment: @JohnGordon Very true, i elaborated some.  The OP would have encountered (and maybe tried to solve) that issue on his own, once the initial bug was gone :)

Answer (score 0):

`file` should be replaced for a string.

```
variable = file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying call `replace` on a `file` object. You are getting that error because the file object has no attribute named `replace`.

If you read the contents of the file into a string, you can replace the values and rewrite the file.

```
print("What would you like your username to be changed to?")

C2 = input()

contents = ""
with open("Info.txt", 'r') as blah:
    contents = blah.read()

with open("Info.txt", 'w') as blah:
    blah.write(contents.replace(A1, C2))
```